# Get name of the key from array, from specific position

Tags: php, arrays

Is there no  built in function for this? I was  only able to find

array_key_first and last;

I made this function , that sort of works, but still...

```
/**
 * Get array  key from position
 */
function get_array_key($arr, $pos = 0)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $mykey[] = $key;
    }
    if (isset($mykey[$pos])) return $mykey[$pos];
}
```

Comment: why not `array_keys($arr)[$pos]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `array_keys`:

```
echo array_keys($arr)[$pos];
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/K2jiv) comparing it to your function.

Comment: What will happen if `$pos` is greater then the array count? Undefined index? Maybe worth adress this case

Comment: @dWinder that's a good point. OPs function silently fails in that case (it doesn't return anything), where this will yield a PHP error, which I actually think is a better result. What were your thoughts on how to deal with it?

Comment: its fine, im working with schema objects for now; and this did help

Comment: I would add `if` statement and return null - but that me - I would leave the OP to choose what the put (throw error?) In the `else` block